# PHP POST adds additional characters before and after the result body

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have php scripts that work well on my local pc, but when they were uploaded in the test server, it behaves unusually. *I remember the scripts worked before in the test server.*

I investigated the script and was able to conclude that whenever I submit POST values to **any** PHP page, the results throw excess characters, like this:

> d
>
> {"success":1}
>
> 0

This is the sample script I used to test the POST which resulted in the above result:

```
<?php
// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);
echo json_encode(array("success"=>1));
```

So basically, all post results throw a line showing a **count** of echoed characters in base 16, followed by the **actual** echoed output, then finally another line showing the **number 0**.

I am seeing the result body with the unwanted characters in chrome's inspect element and chrome's POSTMAN extension. That is what's preventing ALL my ajax json dependent functions to work.

This could be a server problem, but I don't know how to test it to confirm my hunch.

Viewing the script via GET (or by typing the url in the browser) shows the expected `{"success":1}` without the extra characters described above.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

**edit**

I used Firefox, the problem is still occurring.

**edit 2**

As per request, here's one of the many AJAX functions that I use that doesn't work in my test server, but works in my local server...

```
// ...
$.post("costing-calculator.php",
    {   "action": ["retrieve"],
        "name": $("#saveInfo_name").val(),
        "title": $("#saveInfo_title").val(),
        "costing_code": $("#saveInfo_costingCode").val()
    },
    function(data){
        if(data.success){
              console.log(data);
            htmlAlert("Retrieved!", "success");
            $("#retrieveCosting").val("Retrieved!").attr("disabled",null);

            $("input[name=build_type]").prop("checked",null);
            $("input[name=build_type][value='"+data.fields.build_type+"']").prop("checked","checked").change();

            $("#saveInfo_name, #costCalcInput_name").val(data.fields.name || "").change();
            $("#saveInfo_title, #costCalcInput_title").val(data.fields.title || "").change();
            $("#costCalcInput_postcode").val(data.fields.postcode || "").change();
            $("#newInternalArea").val(data.fields.new_internal_area || 0).change();
            $("#renovatedInternalArea").val(data.fields.renovated_internal_area || 0).change();
            $("#newExternalArea").val(data.fields.new_external_area || 0).change();
            $("#renovatedExternalArea").val(data.fields.renovated_external_area || 0).change();
            $("#newDrivewaysPaths").val(data.fields.new_driveways_paths || 0).change();
            $("#newPoolSpa").val(data.fields.new_pool_spa || 0).change();
            $("#renovatedPoolSpa").val(data.fields.renovated_pool_spa || 0).change();

            $("input[name=demolition]").prop("checked",null);
            $("input[name=demolition][value='"+data.fields.demolition+"']").prop("checked","checked");
            if(data.fields.demolition == "Whole house")
                $("#demoWholeHouse").val(data.fields.demo_whole_house_area || 0).change();
            if(data.fields.demolition == "Detailed")
                $("#demoDetailed").val(data.fields.demo_detailed || 0).change();

            $("input[name='excavation[]']").prop("checked",null);
            if(data.fields['excavation[]'] !== undefined && data.fields['excavation[]'].length){
                for (var i = 0; i < data.fields['excavation[]'].length; i++) {
                    $("input[name='excavation[]'][value='"+data.fields['excavation[]'][i]+"']").prop("checked","checked");
                    if(data.fields['excavation[]'][i] == "Bulk Excavation")
                        $("#excavBulk").val(data.fields.excav_bulk || 0).change();
                    if(data.fields['excavation[]'][i] == "Detailed Excavation")
                        $("#excavDetailed").val(data.fields.excav_detailed || 0).change();
                }
            }

            $("#fitOutItemsKitchens").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-Kitchens"] || 0).change();
            $("#fitOutItemsKitchenettes").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-Kitchenettes"] || 0).change();
            $("#fitOutItemsBathrooms").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-Bathrooms"] || 0).change();
            $("#fitOutItemsEnsuites").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-Ensuites"] || 0).change();
            $("#fitOutItemsPowderRooms").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-PowderRooms"] || 0).change();
            $("#fitOutItemsStaircases").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-Staircases"] || 0).change();
            $("#fitOutItemsHomeCinemaRooms").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-HomeCinemaRooms"] || 0).change();
            $("#fitOutItemsLaundry").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-Laundry"] || 0).change();
            $("#fitOutItemsCustom1").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-Custom1"] || 0).change().prop("disabled",data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName1"] && data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName1"]!=customFitoutLabel1?false:true);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomLabel1").text(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName1"] || customFitoutLabel1);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomName1").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName1"] || customFitoutLabel1);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomCost1").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomCost1"]).change().prop("disabled",data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName1"] && data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName1"]!=customFitoutLabel1?false:true);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustom2").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-Custom2"] || 0).change().prop("disabled",data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName2"] && data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName2"]!=customFitoutLabel2?false:true);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomLabel2").text(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName2"] || customFitoutLabel2);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomName2").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName2"] || customFitoutLabel2);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomCost2").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomCost2"]).change().prop("disabled",data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName2"] && data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName2"]!=customFitoutLabel2?false:true);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustom3").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-Custom3"] || 0).change().prop("disabled",data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName3"] && data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName3"]!=customFitoutLabel3?false:true);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomLabel3").text(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName3"] || customFitoutLabel3);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomName3").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName3"] || customFitoutLabel3);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomCost3").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomCost3"]).change().prop("disabled",data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName3"] && data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName3"]!=customFitoutLabel3?false:true);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustom4").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-Custom4"] || 0).change().prop("disabled",data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName4"] && data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName4"]!=customFitoutLabel4?false:true);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomLabel4").text(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName4"] || customFitoutLabel4);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomName4").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName4"] || customFitoutLabel4);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomCost4").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomCost4"]).change().prop("disabled",data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName4"] && data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName4"]!=customFitoutLabel4?false:true);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustom5").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-Custom5"] || 0).change().prop("disabled",data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName5"] && data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName5"]!=customFitoutLabel5?false:true);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomLabel5").text(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName5"] || customFitoutLabel5);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomName5").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName5"] || customFitoutLabel5);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomCost5").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomCost5"]).change().prop("disabled",data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName5"] && data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName5"]!=customFitoutLabel5?false:true);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustom6").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-Custom6"] || 0).change().prop("disabled",data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName6"] && data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName6"]!=customFitoutLabel6?false:true);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomLabel6").text(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName6"] || customFitoutLabel6);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomName6").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName6"] || customFitoutLabel6);
            $("#fitOutItemsCustomCost6").val(data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomCost6"]).change().prop("disabled",data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName6"] && data.fields["fit_out_items-CustomName6"]!=customFitoutLabel6?false:true);

            $("#totalLengthRobe").val(data.fields.total_length_robe || 0).change();
            $("#totalLengthBespoke").val(data.fields.total_length_bespoke || 0).change();
            $("#totalLengthBalustradingExt").val(data.fields.total_length_balustrading_ext || 0).change();
            $("#totalLengthBalustradingInt").val(data.fields.total_length_balustrading_int || 0).change();

            $("input[name=wiring_home_automation]").prop("checked",null);
            $("input[name=wiring_home_automation][value='"+data.fields.wiring_home_automation+"']").prop("checked","checked").change();

            $("input[name=quality_scale]").prop("checked",null);
            $("input[name=quality_scale][value='"+data.fields.quality_scale+"']").prop("checked","checked").change();

            $("input[name=sloping_site]").prop("checked",null);
            $("input[name=sloping_site][value='"+data.fields.sloping_site+"']").prop("checked","checked").change();

            $("input[name=site_access]").prop("checked",null);
            $("input[name=site_access][value='"+data.fields.site_access+"']").prop("checked","checked").change();

            $("input[name=bushfire_affected]").prop("checked",null);
            $("input[name=bushfire_affected][value='"+data.fields.bushfire_affected+"']").prop("checked","checked").change();

            $("input[name=marine_environment]").prop("checked",null);
            $("input[name=marine_environment][value='"+data.fields.marine_environment+"']").prop("checked","checked").change();

            $("input[name=market_conditions]").prop("checked",null);
            $("input[name=market_conditions][value='"+data.fields.market_conditions+"']").prop("checked","checked").change();

            $("input[name=builder_type]").prop("checked",null);
            $("input[name=builder_type][value='"+data.fields.builder_type+"']").prop("checked","checked").change();

            $("input[name=contingency]").prop("checked",null);
            $("input[name=contingency][value='"+data.fields.contingency+"']").prop("checked","checked").click().change();

            $("#contingencyAmount").val(data.fields.contingency_amount || 0).change();

            $("#costCalcInput_email").val(data.fields.cost_email || "").change();

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#buildType").offset().top
            }, 500);

            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#retrieveCosting").val("Retrieve Costing");
            }, 5000);
            id = data.id;
        } else{
            htmlAlert(data.error.messages.join('<br/>'),"error", false);

            if(data.error.fields !== null && data.error.fields !== undefined){
                $.each(data.error.fields, function(index, value){
                    notify($("input[name="+value+"]"), data.error.messages[index]);
                });
            }
            $("#retrieveCosting").val("Retrieve Costing").attr("disabled", null);
        }
    },
    "json"
)
// ...
```

**Edit 3**

*Response Headers*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2016 01:06:00 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
X-SERVER: 716
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=97
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
Via: 1.1 UberGlobal-Cloud
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 613
```

*Request Headers*

```
POST /0-test-pages/costing-calculator.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.aaarchitect.com.au
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 52
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://www.aaarchitect.com.au
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://www.aaarchitect.com.au/0-test-pages/home-building-costing-calculator.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __utma=3608608.1151163053.1424317303.1441072049.1442896000.13; __utmz=3608608.1424317478.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _hp2_id.3414745005=0285466406273470.0064618313.3721268934; _gat=1; BIGipServercbr1lshngpweb-http=2583697580.20480.0000; _hp2_ses.3414745005=*; _hp2_id.3414745005=0285466406273470.3606727761.3721268934; _ga=GA1.3.1151163053.1424317303
```

*Form Data*

```
action%5B%5D=retrieve&name=&title=&costing_code=20ev
```

*Response*

```
4e8
{"error":{"messages":["Invalid costing code."],"fields":["costing_code"]},"id":"c16a5320fa475530d9583c34fd356ef5","success":1,"fields":{"name":"John Cris Test","title":"Test Summary 2","costing_code":"20ev","build_type":"new","year_plan":"2015","new_internal_area":"1","new_external_area":"1","new_driveways_paths":"1","new_pool_spa":"1","demolition":"Detailed","demo_detailed":"2","excavation[]":["Bulk Excavation","Detailed Excavation"],"excav_bulk":"1","excav_detailed":"1","fit_out_items-Kitchens":"1","fit_out_items-Kitchenettes":"1","fit_out_items-Bathrooms":"1","fit_out_items-Ensuites":"1","fit_out_items-PowderRooms":"1","fit_out_items-Staircases":"1","fit_out_items-HomeCinemaRooms":"1","fit_out_items-Laundry":"1","total_length_robe":"1","total_length_bespoke":"1","total_length_balustrading_ext":"1","total_length_balustrading_int":"1","wiring_home_automation":"Full C'bus automation","quality_scale":"3","sloping_site":"Very steep (more than 25 deg)","site_access":"Difficult access","bushfire_affected":"Flame zone affected","marine_environment":"Within 100m of breaking surf","market_conditions":"Recession","cost_name":"John Cris Test","cost_title":"Test Summary 2","cost_postcode":"123","cost_email":"atsalycj@gmail.com","postcode":"123"}}
0
```

Comment: Can you check `auto_prepend_file`and `auto_append_file` in your `PHP.ini`

Comment: wow that was fast... checking now...

auto_append_file and auto_prepend_file is set to "no value" @GennadiyLitvinyuk

Comment: it's not the server. if you viewed it directlyy in the browser and didn't see the extra characters, then the characters are obviously not coming from the server, they are coming from your javascript. there is nothing in your 2 line script that would cause such output. you tagged "ajax" so show your ajax code.

Comment: thanks for the input @Pamblam, I may have wrongly tagged AJAX. I was thinking this problem is preventing my ajax functions to work in my test server. I wanted to get the JSON through ajax POST but as described above, the unwanted characters are showing up.

Comment: @JCLasta I repeat: **It's not your server. Hit the "edit" button and add your AJAX code to the question**.

Comment: i added an ajax code there from my server @Pamblam. thanks :)

Comment: it's the `// a long line of code here` part that we need to see. please check out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Pamblam. I understand. I added the long line of code that you requested.

Comment: Using your tools, can you give us an example of a fully-formed HTTP POST request that's showing up this problem?

Comment: (And also the headers of your response? That looks very suspiciously like [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) to me.) Might be the same as [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506930/weird-json-encoding-using-json-encode)?

Comment: hi @MattGibson, after reading the wiki that you provided, it does sound like that's the one causing the problem. I've edited the question to include the headers, data and response for a sample POST request. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the response body you described in the question is specific to the [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). But it should contain the header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` instead of `Content-Length`.

The only possible cause I know for such a behaviour is a proxy that doesn't understand HTTP 1.1 and doesn't decode the body of the response as indicated by the `Transfer-Encoding` header.

The header `Via` is a sign that the request (and response) passed through a proxy but I cannot tell if UberGlobal-Cloud is to blame.

Comment: I see. While waiting for the response from the host server, to fix my ajax functionalities, I created a json grabber, and my ajax posts are using "text" format instead of "json".

Comment: The transfer encoding takes care of the data transfer, it doesn't care how the content it transfers looks like. It can be anything, plain text, json, html, even images. On the "regular" response the entire body is sent in a single piece. Using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` the response body is sent in small pieces (chunks) each of them being prefixed with a line that contains the size of the chunk formatted as hex number. It's the duty of the HTTP client to join the chunks (and remove the control lines) but only the presence of the `Transfer-Encoding` header tells it to act this way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my case can help somebody.
The mistake was in wrong encoding of request string on a client side. Really I sent json in win-1251 encoding, so server tryed treat it as UTF8 and it leaded to such artefacts.